# How to create scrollable canvas in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, viewbox

I tried this, but I can't scroll the canvas. I tried to handle mousewheel change event of other controls but scrolling is not working. Anybody has idea what I am doing wrong ?

```xml
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both" Height="300" Width="300">
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="20,0,20,0" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Canvas Background="White" Height="300" Width="500">
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="This Is Far Right" Canvas.Left="350" Foreground="Black" />
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try specify width and height of the canvas bigger than the outer element, eg.

`<Canvas Background="White" Width="500" Height="500" />`

Comment: Mouse wheel scrolling is not working. See my updated code in question.

Comment: Vertical mouse wheel scrolling is working on my machine. If you want horizontal scrolling i think you have to implement yourself... (simple mouse wheel is only for vertical scrolling?)

Comment: I don't think so. In my scenario there's no scrolling required in vertical direction, so when mouse wheel is scrolled it should scroll horizontally.